# string_replace and preg_replace for unwanted HTML in Magento 2.0

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I am designing a theme in Magento 2.0 for the first time. I believe it takes too long to locate all files for making simple HTML changes. Instead I figure that I could make a simple PHP script that replaces the unwanted html using `string_replace` and `preg_replace`. Then I could make all changes in one single file.

In what file should I place this script for making changes to all pages?

- I have no problem editing this file when Magento updates to a new
  version.
- I don't mind if it slows down the page load when creating the cache files.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieve by `php`. You need a `jquery` code which can be placed on `footer.phtml` and on `onload` you can traverse your html and replace what you want to replace